# Find code that generates the content of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

In excel VBA, is it possible to jump straight from an object e.g. a cell or chart to see any code that alters its properties?

Comment: You can use `Worksheet_Change` event to check if a particular cell is being changed. But then it won't trap if there were any formatting changes to that cell. For example if the cell was colored. So my question to you would be... What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Please define `jump` when it comes to VBA? I don't think what you are asking is possible, but it is not very clear what you are looking for exactly. Maybe an example would help.

Comment: I would think the best you could do would be "doesn't alter" or "might alter".  Even then, automating that would probably be beyond the scope of a sensible VBA project.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I could get would be to add a Watch expression in VBA:

```
Worksheets("MySheetName").Cells(1,1).Value
```

If you add that expression as a watch with a "break on change" setting and a suitably wide scope (e.g. module), any code that changes the value of that cell (A1) will cause the code to pause in debug mode. You can then see what just changed it.